# How to use the same header with ion-side-menus?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm creating an app using Ionic 1.3.2, and I have one step when user choose your login type, from facebook or from app, after the user make your login it will redirect to other step when has a `<ion-side-menus>` and the user can use the app. The problem is I created the first step (choose login) with `<ion-nav-bar>` and in second step (side-menus) also has `<ion-nav-bar>` on content of `<ion-side-menus>` and the header of first step seems override the header of second step bugging the layout, I want to use the same header on both steps.

My question is, how could I use only one header, in that case header created on first step, and the second step use this header too ?

My scene is like below.

**index.html (first step)**

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">

             <!-- The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate--> 
              <ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-assertive" align-title="center"> 
              </ion-nav-bar>

              <!-- where the initial view template will be rendered -->
              <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  </body>
```

**main.html (first step, where user choose your login type)**

```
  <ion-view view-title="MeuPedido" align-title="center">
    <ion-content>
      <div class="principal">

              <a class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="fbLogin();">Login com Facebook</a>

              <button class="button button-block button-energized" ng-click="goTo('login');">
                  Entrar
              </button>
              <button class="button button-block button-energized" ng-click="goTo('addUsuario');">
                  Cadastrar
              </button>                       
        </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

**sidemenu.html (second step, after user make his login)**

```
<ion-side-menus ng-controller='CtrlSideMenu' data-ng-init="loadImage();">
  <!-- Center content -->
  <ion-side-menu-content>



    <!--app has header on index.html -->
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
      <ion-nav-back-button>        
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left" class="has-header">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>       
    </ion-nav-bar> 



    <ion-nav-view name="tabsContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <!-- Left menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
      <ion-header-bar>
      <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-90 text-center">        
                <img ng-src="{{imageURL}}" class="round_image">
            </div>                 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-90 text-center customTitle">{{nome}}</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content style="margin-top:200px;">
      <ion-list>        
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
          Search
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
          Browse
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
          Playlists
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar bar-footer">
        <h6>Desenvolvido por Iguana Sistemas</h6>        
    </ion-footer-bar>

  </ion-side-menu>


</ion-side-menus>
```

here image of first step, look at in this point has header

[image]

here image of second step, note that header of first step is overriding header inside `ion-side-menus` and bugging the layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want to achieve, but side menu is one thing (it controls the view that appears when you open the side menu)and the the main view is another - is the view that user will see and from here you can open side-menu.  you can have different nav bars for this 2 views. but from your code it looks like you have 1 main view that logs in the user and then changes itself to display the feed and a side-menu.
you multiple options: 1. make the title and color of the nav bar variable and change them with angular. 2. create another view for second step and override the nav bar.
You should have a structure something like this: -> main view(login) ->second view(feed) that also has a side menu